# C# convert string with time zone to datetime HH:mm (UTC)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string to DateTime. The string includes the Time zone.

here is how it looks like

`HH:mm (time zone)`

`04:47 (CEST)`.

The timezone isn't always the same. I have tried using an array of formats, but is there any better way to convert that?
I also readed the [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=net-6.0) but couldn't find any way to convert this one

##### Tryed

```
string[] formats = new[] { "HH:mm (CEST)", "HH:mm (CET)" };
var processedData = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "04:47 (CEST)",
    formats,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None);

Console.WriteLine(processedData);
```

Comment: Why not just split the string by the space and take the first part? Then it's consistent.

Comment: Yeah, but actually I'm getting this string from an API. And store it into the objects, so I Have to change a lot of stuff there but that's not all because that's a timezone, and if I cut it off i will not have a correct time.

Comment: How will you handle timezones where the names overlap, like IST? (Irish Standard Time, India Standard Time, Israel Standard Time).  I don't think your solution is going to work for all cases.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how. Then I will try to find a way to get from API always the same timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace them with the timezone offset and then use the right `ParseExact`-format and `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` to get the universal time(UTC):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] inputs = { "04:47(CEST)", "14:47(CET)" };
    DateTime?[] utcTimes = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, TryParseUtcTime);
}

private static DateTime? TryParseUtcTime(string input)
{
    input = input.Replace("(CEST)", " +2").Replace("(CET)", " +1");
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "HH:mm z", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateTime dt))
    {
        return dt;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qKgvI1